# when disable csrf protection response the unauthorized(401 error)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I used spring version 2.4.1

```
package com.example.backend.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

postman returns 401 authorized error. How to avoid this error and fix it.

Comment: are you sending an OPTIONS request in postman? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpMethod.html.  you may need to change it to HttpMethod.GET

Comment: how can we know, you have provided to little information to reproduce, what does your request look like, maybe you are doing a wrong request, what does your debug logs look like? voted to close.